# Efficient PHP programming using exec

Tags: php, linux, design-patterns, shell

I writing a PHP script program under Linux. In the script, I need call many other system tools/programs using exec to achieve some goals. I know that whenever I run a shell script in terminals, a new child process will be created and run with the parent. If I use too many exec in my PHP script and there should be many processes running back and forth, I assume that would be inefficient because processes are heavy-weighted.

Here is my question: what are the efficient ways and common patterns to approach programming goal in Linux? Will PHP ideal in such situation?

Comment: This is not specific enough. For example, it may be possible to put all the task into one central `exec()` or a daemon shared across all instances of a script, but whether that is possible, completely depends on what your goals *are*

Comment: Could you please be more specific on how to achieve this using a daemon shared across all instances of a script? Any example? Thanks!

Comment: And under what circumstance you use each paradigm?

Comment: It would be easier if you could describe what you want to do. People may come up with concrete solutions then

Comment: What pekka means are system resources. The chance if you use exec might be higher to consume all available resources so that you might need to distribute across nodes. Luckily PHP is perfect for that, just clone your PHP machines and put a load balancer in front to that incomming HTTP requests get distributed across nodes so to have more resources available in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the overhead of using `exec` is more than just a standard PHP function call, I would not consider it expensive at all. It is a pretty effective way of doing things and when you keep security considerations in mind, I'd say there is nothing wrong with it.

You might ask if pre-mature optimization is worth the trouble? I'd say no then.

Comment: I think his question is more about the stuff he is `exec()`ing - and that can indeed become nasty quickly. Imagine 10 users starting an ImageMagick process that takes 200MB of RAM each....

Comment: Lol, imagine you get your local sports team to drive trucks into all houses of your road. Got the idea? EVen if you would have a PHP function that takes 200MB of RAM each and you have got 10 users starting that, the difference to the exec variant would be minimal.

Comment: of course. The PHP part is not really what his question is about, even though he may not know it. In its current state though, this is unanswerable as he's not saying *what* he wants to do